# Integrally Closed in Terms of Galois Theory

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $A$ be a subring. We say $A$ is integrally closed in $K$ if any element $a \in K$ integral over $A$ is contained in $A$.

Does being integrally closed have an interpretation in terms of the automorphisms of $K$?

I have come across a similar observation which goes as follows:

**Lemma:** Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of fields, and let $A \subset L$ be a subring. If $\sigma (A) = A$ for each $\sigma \in [L, L]_K$, then $A$ is integral over $A \cap K$.

**Proof:** Take $a \in A$ and let $f \in K[x]$ be the (monic) minimal polynomial for $a$ over $K$. $f(x)$ factors as $\prod_{\sigma \in [L, L]_K }(x -  \sigma(a))$. Since each $\sigma(a)$ belongs to $A$, the coefficients of $f$ belong to $A$, so that they belong to $A \cap K$. Therefore $a$ is integral over $A \cap K$.

I suspect there should be some way of expressing "integrally closed" with the automorphisms, but I can't quite figure out what it should be.

Of course, this would lead to a description of $\mathcal{O}_K \subset K$ for a Galois number field $K$ in terms of the Galois group, which is the case I am interested in.

Comment: To clarify, does the notation $[L, L]_{K}$ refer to the field automorphisms of $L$ which fix $K$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: $O_K$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ means it is the largest finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. You need that characterization to show $(K:I) =  \{x \in K, x I \subset O_K\} $ is $= a^{-1} J$ for some ideal $J$.

Comment: Do you suspect that can be phrased in terms of the automorphisms?